# Is there a method to get a UITextView with similar surrounding shadow like a UITextField box?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextfield, uitextview

There is a way to get the `UITextView` with the rounded corners and inner shadow-y type border identical to a `UITextField`?

Is there a link or information out there that someone could link toward doing this? I assume it's going to involve subclassing `UITextView` and it's `drawRect` again?

It seems like something that people would commonly want though so I assume it's been done or solved already?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to put a UIImageView under the UITextView, while giving the textview a clear background color. If you use the stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: method on a screencap of a regular textfield, you could easily resize the thing and achieve nice results.
Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

four rounded corners you can do

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then in viewDidLoad

```
[uitextview.layer setCornerRadius:7];
```